# Is fetch() better than list(Model.all().run()) for returning a list from a datastore query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Using Google App Engine Python 2.7 Query Class -

I need to produce a list of results that I pass to my django template.  There are two ways I've found to do this.

1. Use fetch, however in the docs it says that fetch should almost never be used. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_fetch
2. Use run() and then wrap it into list() thereby creating the list object.

Is one preferable to the other in terms of memory usage?  Is there another way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is *why* `fetch` “should almost never be used”. The documentation says that `fetch` will get all the results, therefore having to keep all of them in memory at the same time. If the data you get is big, you will need lots of memory.

You say you can wrap `run` inside `list`. Sure, you can do that, but you will hit exactly the same problem—`list` will force all the elements into memory. So, this solution is actually discouraged on the same basis as using `fetch`.

Now, you could say: so what should I do? The answer is: in most cases you can deal with elements of your data one by one, without keeping them all in memory at the same time. For example, if all you need is to put the result data into a django template, and you know that it will be used at most once in your template, then the django template will happily take any iterator—so you can pass the `run` call result directly without wrapping it into `list`.

Similarly, if you need to do some processing, for example go over the results to find the element with the highest price or ranking, or whatever, you can just iterate over the result of `run`.

But if your usage requires having all the elements in memory (e.g.: your django template uses the data from the query several times), then you have a case where `fetch` or `list(run(…))` actually has sense. In the end—this is just the typical trade-off: if you need for your application to apply an algorithm which requires all the data in memory, you need to pay for it by using up memory. So, you can either redesign your algorithms and usage to work with an iterator, or use `fetch` and pay for it by longer processing times and higher memory usage. Google of course encourages you to do the first thing. And this is what “should almost never be used” actually means.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I must be doing something wrong with Django.  The last time I tried passing it the iterator I recall thinking it balked and needed an actual list.  I'll go back and rework how django handles it from {% for object in itr %}, where itr is being passed from itr = Model.all().run()

Comment: @DanielYoung: remember that what allows iterators to be cheap in memory is that they are one-use only. You cannot use such an iterator twice—for example in two places of a django template, or once in your code, then in django template. This might be the reason you might have observed when you decided that it “balked”.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and your clear and concise answers.  One question remains, would it be favorable to produce an identical iterator twice vs. what I've been doing now?  Either way an algorithm rework is needed.

Comment: @DanielYoung: from my experience keeping it in memory was almost always the best option—a megabyte or two of memory is not much, and in a web application it is rare you deal with more data in a single page view. But it depends on the size and query processing costs. My advise would be—if you know that reworking your algorithm to accept an iterator is going to take more time—go with simpler algorithm (one that probably uses `fetch`), and optimize it only if you'll actually have problems with efficiency.

Comment: If you know how many entities you are getting , say some large number then fetch will be quicker. Run batches,  if you dont know an upper limit of results then run with a bigger batch size is the way to go.